# How to update a file in server using SFTP in Paramiko

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko

I want to go to a path on a remote SFTP server and verify if the file is present. If the file is present, then I want to open the file and update its contents.

Is it possible with SFTP in Paramiko?

Answer (score 1):

Paramiko SFTP client has [`SFTPClient.open`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.open) method that is an equivalent of regular Python `open` function. It returns a file-like object, which you can then use as if you were editing a local file:

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
# ...
ssh.connect(...)
 
sftp = ssh.open_sftp()

with sftp.open("/remote/path/file.txt", "r+") as f:
    f.seek(10)
    f.write(b'foo')
```